# Why can't I refer to property set from outside the module?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have such a simple code:

app.js

```
var pool=require('.database.js')
var oneApi=require('./api/one_api.js')
oneApi.init(pool)
```

one_api.js

```
var pool

(function() {

    module.exports.init=function (conn) {
        pool=conn
    }

    module.exports.some_call = async (irrelevant, params) => {
        ...
        var queryResult=await pool.query("SELECT * FROM Something)
        ...
    }
})();
```

Which works fine. However, I wanted to simplify it a bit:

app.js

```
var pool=require('.database.js')
var oneApi=require('./api/one_api.js')
oneApi.pool=pool
```

one_api.js

```
(function() {
    module.exports.some_call = async (irrelevant, params) => {
        ...
        var queryResult=await pool.query("SELECT * FROM Something)
        ...
    }
})();
```

Here pool becomes undefined.

Can you tell me why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that you can access `init()` because you export it through `module.exports.init`. But your `var pool` is never exported, this way it stays "private" for the `one_api` module. You have to export it: `module.exports.pool`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's helpful. Just out of curiosity, how newApi.pool set from outside and pool referenced inside differ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. :)